# Whenever I connect my bluetooth headphones or earphones I hear buzzing noises.What should I do?

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

I uses Ubuntu 18.04.3. I run it on dual boot with Windows 10. Whenever I connect my Bluetooth headphones or Bluetooth earphones to Windows it works perfectly.When I use Ubuntu if I connect the headphones the sound is clear but the connection breaks often, like if I'm watching a video if my position changes a bit then the connection breaks, like I'm not able to hear stuff. With the earphones I get terribly bad sound quality as well as poor connectivity.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b65d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I added the outputs

Comment: You are unlucky with the device. I am not aware of any fix yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here in this link: [Fixing Bluetooth in Ubuntu, Pop!_OS 18.04](https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6) under "Bluetooth headset playing in profile HSP/HFP (Low quality) instead of A2DP (High Fidelity Playback)".

My headphones are working perfectly on Ubuntu now. I realized that the error was because I didn't have the `audio.conf` file in `/etc/bluetooth`.